# EF Core generating bad SQL

Tags: sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am writing a general repository method like below:

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetEntities<T>(Func<T, bool> condition) 
{
     return _dbContext.Set<T>().AsQueryable<T>().Where(condition).ToList();
}
```

And on some BLL class I am trying to use the method like this:

```
var specificUsersNames = .. // List<string> of names
var users = _usersRepo.GetEntities<User>(x => specificUserNames.Contains(x.Name));
```

After seeing the logs in the console, here's the generated SQL:

```
SELECT [u].[Id], [u].[Name], [u].[PhoneNr], [u].[Address]
FROM [User] AS [u]
```

I have tried using `Any` instead of `Contains` but I get the same result.

It is getting all the rows, but when debugging, it shows only the correct ones.

Any idea why I get this generated SQL?

Comment: What database provider are you using?

Comment: I am using MS Sql

Comment: The key is: use `Expression<Func<T, bool>> condition`.

Comment: And what is `AsQueryable<T>()`?  It's not `DbSet.AsQueryable()`, which is not generic: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbset-1.asqueryable?view=efcore-5.0